# BTree+ Best Leafsize

Tags: algorithm, implementation

I implement a B+Tree with the requirement that the leafs has a fixed size / maximum size. Since this will become an untweakable design decision, I want to know if there are any paper or idea about the best size according to the actions usually performed on B+Trees.

The only idea I came up with is calculating some costs like insertion of values requires to copy. Removal requires copy. Merging nodes, rebalancing leafs.

But in the end the question remains, what would be a good array size and why?

I would love to read a paper about it.

Since I the page size has to be a multiple of 1024, the size must be a power of two (minus the overhead).

Update: As by the comments, you are right. Using a node that fits in a multiple of sectors is prefered.

Comment: It also depends on where you keep the nodes, in memory, on disk, ...

Comment: OP, the question is very unclear, I have no idea how @Henry managed to understand what you're asking. The title says "Best Leafsize" and the only question mark comes after "what would be a good array size and why". Are you sure you mean "Leaf"s and not nodes in general?

Comment: The leaf size (#entries * size(entry)) should be approximately (but not higher than) one [sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector) on the disk, usually, or at least divisible by this size. In fact, it is best if every node in the tree is the size of a sector if possible.

Comment: Not really. BTrees are said to be very cache friendly (locality). The only problem I would see is paging in additional nodes not needed. So in case of disk access it is best to go for nodes fitting in a single page. Especially if you talk about SSD access. I will update the post. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Could you expand on why it's untweakable? I believe when I've implemented one I ended up using a bunch of macros to define constants differently. The best size is usually an empirical question specific to the hardware and often the query load.

Comment: It is basically an inmemory structure that is optimized for SSD caching. Since SSD is just for backup or storing the whole modified data at once, it is unimportant. Making this a in-memory thing mostly.

I separated all the aspects of the node into different areas. Since I have a different memory concept in place. So the idea is just group related memory together. Since this will be modification heavy I will use certain techniques. So I just ask my self whats the best ratio for the nodes. In the end I might benchmark it.